# Как изменить цвет конкретного текста для вывода в консоль а не всей консоли?

Tags: c++

Я хочу отдельный вывод в программе выделить с помощью цветов. Но при использовании таких вариантов как например:

```
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
```

или

```
system("Color 01");
```

Цвет меняется во всей консоли, то есть и предыдущий вывод и последующий. А я хочу сделать что то на подобии такой конструкции например условная функция которая выводит какие то данные и ее обернуть чтобы конкретно эта функция вывела значение конкретного цвета. Пытался сделать такой вариант

```
system("Console 03");
Function();
system("Console 0F");
```

Но опять же такая обертка не работает ибо меняется текст во всей консоли. Можно ли то что я хочу сделать стандартными средствами c++? Или нужно будет подключить какую-нибудь отдельную либу или средствами gdi окрашивать? Подскажите в сторону чего копать надо.

Comment: Посмотрите на ANSI-последовательности и на поддержку конкретных цветовых последовательностей интересующим вас терминалом.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev спасибо, получилось.

Comment: *"Цвет меняется во всей консоли, то есть и предыдущий вывод и последующий"* - Эта функция должна менять только последующий вывод.

Comment: @VTT я просто про ANSI последовательности не знал

Comment: А при чем тут ANSI последовательности? Все должно работать и без них.

Comment: @VTT с помощью последовательности мы можем задавать свойства для определенного куска текста. Посмотрите на мой ответ ниже, я там вывожу 3 слова разного цвета при этом сама консоль имеет дефолтный цвет текста

Answer (score 5):

Если вдруг кто-то захочет сделать подобное, оно достигается путем обертки текста в управляющую последовательность. Например:

```
cout << "\x1b[31mHello\x1b[0m" << endl;
cout << "\x1b[32mHello\x1b[0m" << endl;
cout << "\x1b[33mWorld\x1b[0m" << endl;
```

Получится такой вывод:
[image: Вывод]
Это получается путем добавления к тексту конструкции \x1b[31 где 31 это цвет получающийся при сложении числа 30 и i-го номера цвета. А в конец я добавляю \x1b[0m чтобы вернуть все в исходное состояние. Подробнее можно посмотреть на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI