# Как выделить конкретную часть текста в консоли?

Tags: c++

скажите как выделить конкретную часть текста другим цветом например "красным"  при выводе на консоль. С++

Comment: Зависит от ОС. Винда или линукс?

Comment: Используйте [console escape sequence](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI#%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0) перед выводом текста

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Windows

Comment: Значит предложение avp не сработает. Вроде бы вот это нужно: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, попробую

Comment: Скорее это - [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вроде виндовый терминал понимает ANSI-последовательности? Вот тут вроде прокатило: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031361/Как-изменить-цвет-конкретного-текста-для-вывода-в-консоль-а-не-всей-консоли#comment1755935_1031361

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Хм, у меня на семерке не работает. А на том скрине вроде десятка.